# Counting the length of every element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to find the length of every word in a longer text. The length of every word needs to be returned in a array in the end of the function.

I'm thinking that two loops should be used; one to split the text into words, and one to count the length of every word. But I can't get this to work...

Please help if you have some awesome solutions to my problems! Btw I'm pretty new to JavaScript so please bear over with me.

Comment: Try this `var arr = sentence.split(' ').map(word => word.length);` . `sentence` is the name of your variable which stores your string.

Answer (score 0):

This returns an array of objects containing the word and its length:

```javascript
var sentence = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit';
var arr = sentence.split(' ').map(function(item){
    return {
        word: item,
        length: item.length
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To split the sentence into an array of words use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with, in this case,  `' '` (a space) as what you're separating on. To loop through an array making a new array in the process, use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). So your function would like like:

> 'Hi there!'.split(' ').map((word) => (word.length));

---

But hold up, why is that returning `[1, *6*]? Well, your function currently don't have a way of knowing that "!" isn't part of the word "there".

I'm not how you wish to handle this. I could see an argument for it returning `[1, 5]`, `[1, 5, 1]`, or leave it as `[1, 6]`.

If you want the first option, you could write a regular expression like:

> 'Hi there!'.split(/\b\W*/).filter(Boolean).map((word) => (word.length));
>   // 'filter(Boolean)' removes the empty strings that `split()` inserts according to spec

Though this will return the word "time-out" as `[4,3]`

or for the second option you could try:

> 'Hi there!'.split(/\b\s*/).map((word) => (word.length));

Though this will return "I'm" as `[1,1,1]`. At this point you'll just have to take a look at what regular expression works best for you (which is a separate question.) since "when does a word start and end" is somewhat subjective.